# Making tcolorbox titles section headings

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox

I want to set up a customised [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) where the title of the box is automatically formatted as a section heading. Here's a MWE with my current set up:

```
\documentclass[a0]{a0poster}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=3cm
\columnseprule=0pt
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{info}[1]{boxrule=1.5mm,sharp corners,colback=grey,colframe=black,title=#1,fontupper=\color{black},fonttitle={\color{white}\bf\section{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{info}{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{info}
\lipsum[2-30]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that this creates this:

[image]

Rather than, as desired, this:

[image]

A solution would be welcome.

Comment: Well, you're typesetting the title twice, effectively. `\bf` is deprecated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\section` should go into `title=...`, not again in `fonttitle=`, which is meant for font settings, not for structure levels.

(Well, 'again' is the wrong term: `fonttitle` settings are done first, so `\section` will come first then as well, which is clearly visible in the O.P.'s screenshot)

```
\documentclass[a0]{a0poster}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=3cm
\columnseprule=0pt
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{grey}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{info}[1]{boxrule=1.5mm,sharp corners,colback=grey,colframe=black,title=\protect\section{#1},fontupper=\color{black},fonttitle={\color{white}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{info}{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{info}
\lipsum[2-30]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]